# Email Extension Plugin in Jenkins is not resolving global variables and groovy Template for Outlook emails

Tags: jenkins, outlook, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

**Jenkins version** - 2.275
**Email extension plugin version** - 2.81

**Examples of global variables and templates not getting resolved are -**

1. ${BUILD_NUMBER}
2. ${BUILD_STATUS}
3. groovy-html.template

**Note** - The problem is only seen with Outlook emails, for Gmail I am getting the desired email format.

**UPDTAE **
Strangely it has started to work again without making any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely it has started to work again without making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, be sure to put your string in double-quotes, otherwise variables are not processed, exg:

```
"${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

I also noticed, that they removed variable 'BUILD_STATUS' completely from the global reference list, visible here: /pipeline-syntax/globals

its in named version available as:

```
"${currentBuild.currentResult}"
```